# d3js move a node without dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm moving a node in my d3.js graph using the following code:

```
d3.select("#"+ nodeid).attr("x",x);
d3.select("#"+ nodeid).attr("y",y);
```

This works fine, but when I start dragging on the node again, it 'jumps' back to its old position and starts moving from there.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just adding this to the code as well

```
d3.select("#"+ nodeid).data([{x: x, y: y}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the DOM element (the graphic), but not the underlying data, and the dragstart event is using the original location that's still stored in the data.

Try something like this:

```
force.setNodeCoords = function (id, x, y) {
    var fnodes = force.nodes();
    fnodes[id].x = x;
    fnodes[id].y = y;
    force.nodes(fnodes);
    svg.selectAll("circle.node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
};
```

(where `svg` is your SVG or other parent div, and `node` is the class of your nodes)

You'll probably also want to update the lines/links!

Comment: Than you very much for this. Im sure it works but I found a easy fix.