# Moving a node in a tree with its link and subtree but without dragging

Tags: d3.js, javascript

I am trying to move a node in a d3.js tree based on this [example](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html).

I would like to move the node called  "Level 2: A. So I use the following code:

```
var nodeToMove = node.filter(function(d) { return d.name === "Level 2: A" })
nodeToMove.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x + 100) + "," + (d.y + 100) + ")"; });
```

But if I do so, only the node is moving but not the link or the subtree.
The result can be seen on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/addggjvm/)

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837837/d3js-move-a-node-without-dragging) has been asked, but one solution is not moving the link and the other is probably based on a force layout which is not my case.

Comment: It'd be easier if you posted your code, especially to make it clear how the similar question didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I have my post accordingly.