# How do I move all selected nodes at once ? D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph made in D3.

I have the ability to drag a box over nodes and change their attribute to 'selected'.

What I wish to do now is move all these selected nodes at once. Here is my drag function'

```
function dragstart(d, i) 
{
    force.stop(); //-stop the force layout as soon as you move nodes
}

function dragmove(d, i) //-change coordinates of nodes and lines ???
{
    d.px += d3.event.dx;
    d.py += d3.event.dy;
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy; 
    tick();
}
function dragend(d, i) //-when you stop dragging the node
{
    d.fixed = true; //-D3 giving the node a fixed attribute
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true); //-changing nodes CSS class
    tick(); //-update positions
}
```

How do I apply this so that I move all the selected nodes at once ?

Comment: may be see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837837/d3js-move-a-node-without-dragging

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you meant that you changed the class of the nodes to 'selected' and not their attribute. I'm a beginner in D3js, but here's what I think should happen:

```
d3.behaviour.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function() {
        d3.selectAll('.selected').each(dragstart(d,i))
    }) 
    .on("drag", function() {
        d3.selectAll('.selected').each(dragmove(d,i))
    }) 
    .on("dragend", function() {
        d3.selectAll('.selected').each(dragend(d,i))
    })
```

Depending on what your function `tick()` does, this may work for you.